# Spring Boot Reactive - How to convert Array response to actual DTO object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am developing Spring Boot 2.7.0 and Reactive Microservices using Spring WebFlux.

Below is the code

```
public void placeOrder(OrderRequest orderRequest) {
        List<OrderLineItems> orderLineItems = orderRequest.getOrderLineItemsDtoList()
                .stream()
                .map(this::mapToDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Order order = new Order();
        order.setOrderNumber(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        order.setOrderLineItemsList(orderLineItems);


        List<String> skuCodes = order.getOrderLineItemsList()
                .stream()
                .map(orderLineItem -> orderLineItem.getSkuCode())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Call Inventory Service, and place order if product is in stock
        InventoryResponse[] inventoryResponsArray = webClient.get()
                .uri("http://localhost:8092/api/inventory",
                        uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.queryParam("skuCode", skuCodes).build())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(InventoryResponse[].class)
                .block();

        boolean allProductsInStock = Arrays.stream(inventoryResponsArray)
                .allMatch(InventoryResponse::isInStock);

        if(allProductsInStock){
            orderRepository.save(order);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Product is not in stock, please try again later");
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to combine below two codes into one?

```
// Call Inventory Service, and place order if product is in stock
        InventoryResponse[] inventoryResponsArray = webClient.get()
                .uri("http://localhost:8092/api/inventory",
                        uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.queryParam("skuCode", skuCodes).build())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(InventoryResponse[].class)
                .block();

        boolean allProductsInStock = Arrays.stream(inventoryResponsArray)
                .allMatch(InventoryResponse::isInStock);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of the simplest solution would be below:

```
// Call Inventory Service, and place order if product is in stock
boolean allProductsInStock = webClient.get()
                .uri("http://localhost:8092/api/inventory", uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.queryParam("skuCode", skuCodes).build())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(InventoryResponse[].class)
                .map(e -> Arrays.stream(e))
                .block()
                .allMatch(InventoryResponse::isInStock);
```